# How to step in one function after the function be executed in gdb?

Tags: gdb

In gdb, I can call one function with command "call", but how can I step in the function? I don't want to restart the program, but the function had been executed, gdb will execute next statement, and I don't know how to recall the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb has [reverse debugging ability](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/news/reversible.html). You can use `reverse-step` here and then run your function once again.

Comment: (gdb) reverse-step
Target child does not support this command.

Comment: And I want to step in one function at anywhere to debug it, not just reverse.

Comment: You can set breakpoint on function and call it from gdb command line. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I have set breakpoint in the function, then I call it with command "call", but the function just be executed, not stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you want to step into the function you use the gdb command `call` to execute. Thus you need to set a `breakpoint` at this function then execute it. That is the way I always do when I want to step in a function in anytime.
If it does not step in this function, I think it probably has some problems in the symbol table which store the information about the function and its source code. You have to make sure the table is right by recompiling it with `-g`.